# How does Django decide what in the model will be assigned an _id?

Tags: python, django

How does Django decide what in the model will be assigned an _id, when generated automatically on 'syncdb'? (from this tut https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/intro/tutorial01/)

Secondly, when I run a 'p.save()', how does Django assign the id=i number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the exact page you linked:

> By convention, Django appends "_id" to the foreign key field name.

(In other words, `_id` gets suffixed to any `models.ForeignKey()` fields.)

Every model in Django has an `id` field that is specific to that model (which is what `p.id` is, there). This is used when referencing a given item from that model. It's called a "primary key". It's typically set via simply looking at what the highest current primary key is for that model, and then adding 1.

For instance, the very first instance of a model you create will probably have id=1. The second would then have id=2, and so on.

Comment: I thought it was the database that provides the primary key value.

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel Depends on what database is being used. (My answer in that regard wasn't meant to be specific, just a general description of the pattern used for primary keys. That might be an autoincrement field in the DB, it might be Django setting it, etc.)